# Is there a cleaner way to check a hashed password than this?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-5.5

so far how i check for hashed passwords is the following is there a way to make this cleaner and possibly quicker for if the database grew lager than a test one at home/university?

```
<?php
    $pass = array();
    $index =0;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM admins");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $pass[$index] = $row['password'];
        $newhash = $pass[$index];
        if (password_verify($password, $newhash)) {
            echo "Password Matched";
        } else {
        }
    }
?>
```

Edit: Its been pointed out to add a userid but my orginal question was the way I'm verifying the data is this the best way or is there an optimized way to do so?

Comment: Select the user first. `SELECT * FROM admins where email = ?` or however you identify an admin. You also should select the column, not `*`.

Comment: Your code might return multiple matches multiple people have the same password. Throw in a `WHERE` to match the username.¨

Comment: You probably should have a userid and select that row explicitly (eg. `SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `id` = ...`), this way you're just checking if the password matches **anyones** ?

Comment: Gordon, be careful when approving edits, that edit changed the code (presumably the OP had the correct code (no errors mentioned) but that might not always be the case)

Comment: @chris85 You're totally right, I fixed it instinctively without even thinking about it. It was missing 1 curly bracket.

Comment: @Tumnus Hard to say without the exact code. Codereview might be a better site for this question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. Fetch the user record based on user id or username, then check if the password for that record verifies.

Comment: First, hash the input password, then query the admins table for accounts with same hash. no looping or calling password_verify multiple times.

Comment: @GordonBell - No, that won't work when using `password_hash()`. It generates a different salt every time it's called and the strings will always be different. You need to check the raw, unmodified password against the stored hash when using `password_verify()`.

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't used PHP in a few years and see there's no longer a salt option for password_hash().

Comment: @GordonBell Well, there actually is, but it's deprecated. Finally. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As chris says you really should only select the row containing the asserted identity. While it is possible that two different admins could have the same password, as long as you created the stored password with password_hash() it is improbable that your current code would miss-identify a user (because each account should get a randomly assigned salt for the hash) ; ccKep's comment is probably wrong.

So that implies a query like:

```
SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=?
```

This eliminates the need to iterate through multiple rows in the resultset in your php code.

If you also add an index on username, then it will go even faster as the dbms has less work to do. A unique index simplifies the problem of checking for duplicate accounts.

Since the value of the hashed password is dependent on the salt - which is effectively unique per row, there is no way to optimize the query performance around the hash or the cleartext of the password - you need to use the asserted identity; Graham's suggestion of searching based on the hashed password is wrong.

In practice, if the site has any significant asset value you should also be limiting the rate of logons to protect against brute force attacks, hence a better query would look something like:

```
SELECT password
FROM admins
WHERE username=?
AND 5 < (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM login_failures
  WHERE client_ip = INET_ATON( ? )
  AND attempt_timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```